# Phone authentication using Twilio Nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to use twilio to send SMS for OTP authentication using nodejs and I'm getting an error. Kindly, can somebody help me debug it. Below is my code to send the OTP SMS.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const twilio = require("twilio")(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)

const sendOTP = async(req, res)=>{
   const phoneNumber = req.body
       twilio.verify.services(process.env.TWILIO_SERVICE_SID)
       .verifications.create({
        to: `+${phoneNumber}`,
        channel: 'sms'
       }).then((data)=>{
        res.status(200).send({
            message: 'Verification is sent',
            phonenumber: phoneNumber,
            data
        })
       })
}
```

Error:

```
   twilio.verify.services(process.env.TWILIO_SERVICE_SID)
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Is there any output?

Comment: I'm not getting any output

Comment: From this doc https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/quickstarts/node-express
it seems the correct way is twilio.verify.v2.services. You are missing "v2"

Comment: "status": 400,
        "code": 60200,
        "moreInfo": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200". That is what I'm getting now

Comment: If you print the twilio instance using a console.log, what's bring?! Apparently your instance doesn't bring the API services.

Comment: @Stefano Leone, I have tried your code from the documentation and facing anothrt error  ' status: 
 400,
  code: 60200,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200'

Comment: That's probably because your phone number is undefined or incorrect. It's all written in the doc.

Comment: It's defined correctly. I'll try to figure out what might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and delete twilio from the `node_modules` folder and re-install it.

```bash
npm i twilio
```

Comment: I got a solution, I was using Message service instead of verification service.